# Lion Server iCal Location/Resource Calendar

Tags: ical, server.app, caldav

I have a Lion Server with iCal enabled.

Trying to set up some location and resource calendars, accessing them from Ubuntu clients, how can I work out the URL of these calendars?

I have worked it out for a user already (http://lions:8008/calendars/users/user123/calendar/), is there a way perhaps to see URLs on the server?

Answer (score 2):

In iCal create a calendar entry with your resource or location in the invitation. Select the resource and click on the disclosure (the downward pointing triangle). Choose "Copy Invitee Address", your clipboard will have the uuid (unique id) of the resource, something like:

```
urn:uuid:0d426b70-8294-41a7-8b34-c2ee24cde743
```

Now remove the urn prefix ('urn:uuid:') and plug this into your browser for more details like so:

```
https://server/principals/__uids__/0d426b70-8294-41a7-8b34-c2ee24cde743/
```

Or for a caldav url use:

```
http://server:8008/calendars/__uids__/0d426b70-8294-41a7-8b34-c2ee24cde743/calendar
```

Unfortunately, on Lion Server I wasn't able to have users subscribe to this url due to permissions. Hopefully you will have better luck than I on that part.